# Как правильно указать дату/время в POST параметре?

Tags: php, curl, symfony2

Пытаюсь запостить данные curl'ом так:

```
curl.exe --data "caption=test&description=test&start_plan=2015-10-16 10:22:45&owner=1" localhost:8000/api/test/
```

"start_plan" DATETIME
Но symfony ругается, что это поле не может быть нулевым

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'start_plan' cannot be null
```

Может я не так указываю параметр?

Нужно всего лишь заглянуть в профилировщик

```
Message                               Origin                              Cause
This value is not valid.    start_plan       Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).children[start_plan] = 2015-10-16 10:22:45
```

этот объект содержит в себе еще и другие (date, time)

```
[
  date => [
    year => , 
    month => , 
    day => 
  ], 
  time => [
    hour => , 
    minute => 
  ]
]
```

Как правильно указать это в запросе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас же все написано. Строка не проходит валидацию, а вместо нее подставляется null. [Это](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) должно вам помочь. И я настоятельно не рекомендую преобразовывать данные в контроллере, это порочная практика, лучше разобраться с трансформером.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как должна выглядеть строка, что бы была валидной?

Comment: Никак, строку нужно преобразовать в объект DateTime.

Comment: а документации на русском случайно нет? с английским тяжко

Comment: Можете [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/152539/) почитать, но статья старая, код оттуда лучше не брать.

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, зачем писать свой трансформер, если уже вроде как есть стандартный? http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/DateTimeToStringTransformer.html

Comment: Конечно, мое упущение используйте стандартный =)